# How can i increase the block number in testrpc?

Tags: solidity, testrpc, evm, block-interval

I have the contract which has the dependencies on the block.number so in my javascript test cases I want block number jump. I know about the `eth_mine` but it will mine only the current block or work for one block. It doesn't take any parameter to increase a large number of blocks.

Can anybody have any possible ways to achieve this task?